# Programmatically set console window size and position

Tags: c#, windows, console, position, z-index

I would like to open multiple console programs on my desktop.
This is what I have to do everytime:
1.Right click Desktop->Screen resolution->Detect (4 monitors).
2.Open 16 different console programs (4 per screen).
3.Clicking on all windows to get the Z-order correctly.
3.Right click Taskbar->Show Windows Stacked (to organize all 16 windows to perfect squares, 4 on each screen in order of z-index).

Is there a way to do even just a part of this programmatically to help this go quicker?

Answer (score 18):

You can use the windows API to move your console window. Use DllImport to declare the WinApi functions you want to use:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
```

Then call them: e.g.

```
IntPtr ptr = GetConsoleWindow();
MoveWindow(ptr, 0, 0, 1000, 400, true);
```

You can use further WinApi function as `SetWindowPos`. You can find the DllImport syntax by searching the web for `PInvoke` and the name of the function. Follow the explanations there and in MSDN.

Comment: Worked like bomb!! ThankQ very much - you made my life a whole lot easier.May you be showered with blessings

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with VS2019.   The API works the first round but doesn't move the window with x,y.   Then on the second run, the application locks up, before ever executing Main()..

Comment: @Chizl works fine for me.  I am using VS2022, but I doubt that it was broken in VS2019 and fixed later. Most likely, you have some other kind of problem.

Comment: @Chizl no problem. Deleting comment.