# How to always open Console application at some specific point on the screen?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, console-application

When a Console application is started in Visual Studio it opens at some random point on the screen. Sometimes at the top left corner, sometimes at the center another time somewhere else. This is very annoying and I always have to move it away becase it's hiding the output window etc.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to always open the console at some specific point on the screen so that I don't have to move it around each time I want to debug my application?

Comment: See posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35263590/programmatically-set-console-window-size-and-position?rq=1

Comment: @jdweng oh, thanks! I was so close, if I only had looked for _position_ and not _open_ ;-)

Comment: I do not like this website for giving people negative points just because they do not know the correct words to perform a google search.  OPs do not always know the correct method for doing a search.  I often have to do two or three searches before I get the right results.

Comment: @jdweng wow, and the other answer got its first two votes after two years since asking just a minute ago... probably from me and you :-o  and you're right, it didn't take long until the first downvote..